# project locker (svn) and delphixe7/xe8

Tags: delphi-xe8

I use [ProjectLocker](http://projectlocker.com/) for my offsite SVN repository.  Now that XE7 and XE8 support SVN, I can not get either to connect to it without getting a 500 server error, so I still must use Tortoise.  I know this is typically a sever issue, but for what ever reason, it seems XE7 and XE8 may be passing the credentials differently than project locker is expecting.

Comment: SVN has been supported by the IDE since around XE

Comment: What makes you think that this is related to ProjectLocker. If Tortoise can see the repo, then why would any other SVN client have a problem? If you think it is related to credentials in one way or another, could you tell us the technical details of how you are passing credentials, and how ProjectLocker expects them.

Comment: Client apps don't generate 500 server errors.  The issue is in the Delphi IDE product which I don't have source code; it is not an app that was just written in Delphi.  I'm most interested to find if anyone uses project-locker and Delphi XE7 or XE8 in combination since these product capabilities have been available for over a year.

Comment: How does ProjectLocker expect authentication to be provided?